# How to debug slow typing in Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, performance, ide

Typing in Visual Studio feels often very *sluggish*. Like I'm typing in mud. I tried researching this forever on Google, but can't find a cause.

I have a high performance laptop that has no problems with running other tools. I have the feeling that it wasn't a problem in the beginning.

Is there somehow that I can debug performance of Visual Studio itself? Maybe it's some rogue extension or option that I can disable, because I don't use it anyway.

After every letter I type I see VS starts "low running background tasks" light up:

[image]

Despite that I assume it shouldn't have influence on typing performance, I want to exclude everything.

I also found the **Performance Manager**, but it seems to be empty:

[image: Performance Manager]

Question:

**Is there any way to debug VS performance myself**? To i.e. find rogue settings or extensions?

**Update:**

As asked by @rustyx, here is an export. I use at the moment VS 2019 Preview - but I'm having the same problems with the normal release. Should be pretty vanilla.

```
{   "version": "1.0",   "components": [
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.3.1",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.SDK",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.1.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.DevelopmentTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp.WebTemplates",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DockerTools",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Web",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.SDK",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.2.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentPrerequisites",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.3.8",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.Diagnostics",
    "Microsoft.Component.MSBuild",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating",
    "Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.RazorExtension",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IISExpress",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.ADAL",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.LocalDB.Runtime",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Common.Azure.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.CLR",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.MSODBC.SQL",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.MSSQL.CMDLnUtils",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.2.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources",
    "Component.Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IntelliCode",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.1.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.TargetingPacks.Common",
    "Microsoft.Net.Core.Component.SDK.2.1",
    "Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.AzureFunctions",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.AzureFunctions",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Compute.Emulator",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Storage.Emulator",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.ClientLibs",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.AuthoringTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CloudExplorer",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web.CloudTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.EntityFramework",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AspNet45",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AppInsights.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WebDeploy",
    "Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites",
    "Microsoft.ComponentGroup.Blend",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DotNetModelBuilder",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.3.5.DeveloperTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Unity",
    "Component.UnityEngine.x64",
    "Component.UnityEngine.x86",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedGame",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data"   ] }
```

Comment: How did you install it? Did you install any 3rd-party plugins? Perform an [export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/import-export-installation-configurations?view=vs-2019) of the configuration and edit the result into the question.

Comment: Hi @rustyx, thanks for your response. I've updated my question!

Comment: I have the same except also NativeDesktop and no ManagedGame/UnityEngine components. I have no background tasks/no sluggishness.

Comment: Hi @rustyx, thanks for getting back to me. Just to be sure I temporarily removed Unity. I've also disabled Live Code Analysis and Diagnostics. Let's see if it helps a bit.

Comment: Would you know any way to actually profile VS itself? Then hopoefully I could just see in what kind of modules it is spending unnecessary time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PerfView to collect an ETW trace for Visual Studio operations: [How to: Diagnose UI delays caused by extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-diagnose-ui-delays-caused-by-extensions?view=vs-2019)